# What happens if you delete your Nintendo Network ID, and where do the badges go?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u, nintendo-network-id

I want to link my new Wii U ID to my 3DS but I don't know what happens to badges.

Comment: Badges are saved online (you can't keep any badge if you play offline), so they are probably bound to your NNID

Answer (score 1):

You can format the system to remove the Nintendo Network ID without deleting it. Nintendo Network accounts removed in this way will not be deleted from the Wii U (if linked), and can be relinked to the same Nintendo 3DS system again in the future. For more information click [here](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/258)

Deleting a Nintendo Network ID will also delete the following information associated to the account: Nintendo eShop activity and balance, Friend List, Miiverse activity, and registered e-mail address